# ffmpeg concat videos causes mess in timestamp

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to concat some standard mp4 videos and I believe those have exactly the same format and codec.

```
Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4836 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4836 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4723 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5487 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
```

Except: the videos have a slight difference in FPS: one is 23.976553, and one is 23.975986, etc.

I tried to use the very common process: 
`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i file_list.txt -c copy output.mp4`
There is a warning but I am not sure:
[screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sQOk.png)

When I look through the output mp4, it will crash if I locate the scrub bar to the second portion. [screenshot of crashed video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kgde.jpg) 
For example, 10 mins for the 4 input videos each, the video will crash if I locate the scrub bar to the 11 min when I open the video.

If I move scrub bar near to where the split was(for example 9 mins 50 secs), and let it play through the split, and I now locate the scrub bar in the second potion to where ever I want.

How should I pass additional parameters in `ffmpeg` to avoid that? I know it might be something wrong with the timestamp but I don't know how to fix that. 
PS: 1. I have tried IINA, QuickTime, Movist, and the same issue occurs. 
2. `ffmpeg -i input_video` gives me a warning: `stream 0, timescale not set`

Comment: Why don't you try [Concatenation of files with different codecs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec)?

Comment: Not a warning, but just a message saying that a bitstream filter was automatically applied. You can ignore it. (Next time please copy and paste text instead of making images of text.) How do you know the fps are different when the  info you listed shows them being all the same?